# Does my routine effect my health and age?

Tags: exercise

i want to share my routine and to know its health effects.
i am 18 years old and i don't play any sports or exercise.I spend my entire day in my room i go out about 2 3 times a day and that to on my bike.I love to eat junk food and from hotels.I eat a lot bit still i am skinny.After eating i go to bed and lie there no exercise or physical work at all.I feel depressed all the time.

what health effects it will have on me?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend seeing a doctor.  We can't give you medical advice or prognosis.  But realize that you already have some symptoms including depression, anhedonia, thin despite eating a lot, maybe fatigue.  Sedentary behavior and depression can make a vicious cycle. There's a lot of research on sedentary lifestyle and inflammation including cardiovascular disease, blood pressure, diabetes, and other conditions in the long run.  See a doctor about the depression at the very least, but make a list of your symptoms, medical history, what you eat, and take it with you with a list of questions.

Comment: You could re-ask your question specifically about the long term effects of sedentary lifestyle, which is the root of your question it seems.  Google it to try to learn about it, then re-ask a question about something you want to understand better about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any routine and habits affect a persons health, for better or worse. There is no way anyone can tell you what health affects your routine will have on you, only that it increases or decreases your risks for certain diseases.

A sedentary lifestyle, increases risks of disease, both physical and mental. See:  https://www.lifespanfitn.ess.com/workplace/resources/articles/health-risks-of-a-sedentary-lifestyle

Having a routine such as using a bike as transportation can help reduce these risks, because bike riding is a form of exercise.  However,being consistently active throughout the day is best.

Diet also affects people, the healthier you eat, and the less junk you eat the better.  Sometimes peoples poor lifestyle choices do not catch up to them until later in life, or they may find that problems they never thought would happen to them, catch up to them sooner than they would like.